# Getting a value from from a list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a class and in that class there is a function that returns a list of type Clients, the list contains all the information about the client, but now where I want to know how can I access the Name only for example of the list.. please see below

Function in ClientsInfo class:

```
public List<Clients> GetClientsByID(int clientID)
{  
    ClientsData cData = new ClientsData();

    List<Clients> listClients = new List<Clients>();

    DataTable dtClients = cData.GetClientsByID(clientID).Tables[0];

    foreach (DataRow row in dtClients.Rows)
    {
        this.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
        this.Address = row["Address"].ToString();
        this.BussinessName = row["Bussiness"].ToString();
     }

    listClients.Add(this);

    return listClients;
}
```

Name, Address and Bussiness are a property in this class.. now I am calling this list from somewhere else like this

```
 List<Clients> clientL = ClientsInfo.GetClientsByID(client_id);
```

Now i got the information stored in clientL, how do I retrieve the Name only? of the client?

Comment: Which client?  You have a list of them?

Comment: Try this: clientL[somePosition].Name

Comment: i just want the first client in that list...

Comment: Why are you getting a list of clients by client_Id? Shouldn't there only be one client with a particular client_Id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, so you can use LINQ. I'd urge you to use LINQ in the `GetClientsByID` code as well, in fact, but leaving that aside...

Well you've got *multiple* clients here, not just one. So you can get the multiple names with:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = clientL.Select(x => x.Name);
```

or as a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> names = clientL.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

If you're certain there's going to be exactly one value you can use `Single`:

```
string name = clientL.Select(x => x.Name).Single();
```

If there could be zero or one, you can use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
// name will be null if clientL was empty
string name = clientL.Select(x => x.Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

(There's also `First`, `FirstOrDefault` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Well since all you're doing is creating a list of one item..
Assuming Name is a public property..

```
clientL[0].Name
```

should do it

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to retrieve this information:

```
List<string> clientNames = clientL.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ methods for this:

```
string clientName = clientL.Where(client => client.ID == 1).Select(client => client.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or to retrieve all the names:

```
List<string> clientNameList = clientL.Select(client => client.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
List<string> clientL = ClientsInfo.GetClientsByID(client_id).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of names only.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
var names = from c in ClientsInfo.GetClientsByID(client_id)
            select c.Name;
```

`names` is then an `IEnumerable<string>` containing all names.

If thats not what you want please explain your question again.